# Is there an undocumented way to reinitialize a replication subscription via transact-sql in SQL Server 2000

Tags: replication, sql-server

Is there an undocumented way to reinitialize a replication subscription via transact-sql in SQL Server 2000, or do you have to use Enterprise Manager or SQL-DMO as mentioned in SQL Server Books Online?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean replication or log shipping?

Comment: replication. Does replication use log shipping or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: They're totally unrelated, so that's why I wanted to clarify it. Thanks for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this system stored procedure `sp_reinitsubscription`, which marks the subscription for reinitialization. Here is the [Transact-SQL Reference for SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239377(SQL.80).aspx).

Syntax:

```
sp_reinitsubscription [ [ @publication = ] 'publication' ]
    [ , [ @article = ] 'article' ]
    , [ @subscriber = ] 'subscriber'
    [ , [ @destination_db = ] 'destination_db']
    [ , [ @for_schema_change = ] 'for_schema_change']
```

Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role, members of the db_owner fixed database role, or the creator of the subscription can execute it.